# Lists the profile from the same id 5 times

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a follower list. But it lists the profile from the same id 5 times. As seen in the photo below. I couldn't find a solution. Can you help me. My codes are as follows.....................................................................................................................................................................

[image]

Follow_card

```
class _FollowCardState extends State<FollowCard> {
  List<dynamic> followList = []; 

  getdata() async {
    List<dynamic> followers = [];

    final currentUserSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    
    List<String> followIds =
        List.from(currentUserSnapshot.data()!['following']);
    // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
    for (int i = 0; i < followIds.length; i++) {
      var followId = followIds[i];
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(followId)
          .get();

     
      followers.add(data);
    }
    setState(() => followList = followers);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: followList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var followerItem = followList[index];
            print('photoUrl');

            return _buildFollowersCard(followerItem['photoUrl'],
                followerItem['username'], followerItem['uid']);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFollowersCard(String photoUrl, String username, String uid) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: mobileBackgroundColor,
      child: Card(
        child: Column(children: [
          //Header
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 4,
              horizontal: 16,
            ).copyWith(right: 0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 16,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    photoUrl,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ProfileScreen(uid: uid)));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            username,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Follow_screen

```
class _FollowScreenState extends State<FollowScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'Resim/logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FollowCard(
              snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `FollowScreen` is passing the user as a parameter to `FollowCard` (the `snap` property) but it's not being used anywhere inside it. Maybe the problem is exactly this because `FollowCard` is fetching again the users instead of using the `snap` user. This way `FollowCard` lists all followers from the first user it finds.

To fix this just use the `snap` as the follower user. It's going to be something like this:

```
class FollowScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userId;
  const FollowScreen({required this.userId, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowScreen> createState() => _FollowScreenState();
}

class _FollowScreenState extends State<FollowScreen> {
  List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> followList = [];
  late final Future _future;

  getdata() async {
    final user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(widget.userId)
        .get();

    List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> followers = [];
    List<String> followIds = List.from(user['following']);
    // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
    for (int i = 0; i < followIds.length; i++) {
      var followId = followIds[i];
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(followId)
          .get();

      followers.add(data);
    }
    setState(() => followList = followers);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = getdata();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'Resim/logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
              followList.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: followList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FollowCard(
              snap: followList[index],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FollowCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snap;
  const FollowCard({required this.snap, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowCard> createState() => _FollowCardState();
}

class _FollowCardState extends State<FollowCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildFollowersCard(
        widget.snap['photoUrl'], widget.snap['username'], widget.snap['uid']);
  }

  Widget _buildFollowersCard(String photoUrl, String username, String uid) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      width: double.infinity,
      // color: mobileBackgroundColor,
      child: Card(
        child: Column(children: [
          //Header
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 4,
              horizontal: 16,
            ).copyWith(right: 0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 16,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    photoUrl,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Container()));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            username,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```